# How to fix camera not turning(Black Screen) on when using Agora SDK?

Tags: android, android-10.0, agora.io

am using latest Agora SDK for voice/video call
In voice call i cant hear recivers voice and in video call
i can't see any video neither the reciver can see my video
(I have set permissions and they are all ok)
(I have pasted sample code in my app and replaced ids but in sample app it was working there were no issues but in my app the following issue occurs)

the only thing which is okay is that atleast its connecting.

Testing Device = Android 10
Platform = Android

Comment: Hi, there are some questions i want to clarify: In the voice call, can the receiver hear your voice? And in the video call, is voice feature working fine?

Comment: no voice feature was not woking in the latest 3.0.1 but then i replaced it with 2.9.2 and it worked.. i guess latest has some bugs with Androi 10

Comment: Would you like to share your code? The SDK should work on Android 10. You said it's connecting, but how your know it is connecting since voice and video are not working?

Comment: i have print a toast when anyone join by channel .. and that appear means it connects

Comment: Are you use the onRemoteVideoStateChanged (https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html#a93ebe88d2544253bf4b13faf34873131) call back to set the remote video? Is this callback been triggered?

Comment: yes it was triggerd latest library has some bugs with android 10

Comment: Is this issue fixed? Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @sri issues was fixed in latest SDK

Comment: @Krishna did you used this SDK dependencies ? implementation 'com.github.agorabuilder:agora-full-preview:4.0.0'